# Using the same object to compare each others vectors

Tags: c++, oop, vector, this

Suppose I create a constructor `Set::Set(vector<int> &v)` that takes a vector and saves it. 
And I have a Union method which takes argument of type Set and compare its vector with the contents of the originalSet which was initialized from the constructor in the beginning.

How do you go about doing this with the `this` operator? I know how the union function works, but what I don't understand is how to attain the vector from the argument of the Union method.

```
class Set
{
public:
    Set(vector<int> &);
    void setter(vector<int> &);
    Set Union(Set);


private:
    vector<int> originalSet;
};



Set Set::Union(Set s)
{


}


Set::Set(vector<int> &v)
{
    setter(v);

}

void Set::setter(vector <int> &v)
{
    originalSet = v;
}
```

Comment: what about a getter method? I don't fully understand your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function:

```
Set Set::Union(const Set& s) // take by const&
{
    originalSet; // this is the set owned by "this" object
    s.originalSet; // this is the set owned the Set passed in

    // so one [wrong] implementation might be to just combine them
    Set full(originalSet);
    full.originalSet.insert(full.originalSet.back(), 
        s.originalSet.begin(),
        s.originalSet.end());
    return full;
}
```

That is not the correct implementation of `Union` obviously, but it should show you the tools you need to write it correctly.